# How to control the rendering of a menu in Orchard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have the following problem: I'm making a site in Orchard and have to apply a design made by some design company. They delivered html and CSS (+ LESS) and I have to make it into a theme. 
I get it done for the most part except the menu's. I want to apply a class to the **nav** tag in the following code, but I can't make any alternates for that end up rendering it.

```
<article class="widget-navigation widget-menu-widget widget" shape-id="18">
<nav shape-id="19">
    <ul class="menu menu-main-menu" shape-id="19">
<li class="current first" shape-id="22">
    <a href="/" shape-id="22">Home</a> 
</li>
<li shape-id="24">
<a href="/Something1" shape-id="24">Something1</a>
</li>
<li shape-id="26">
<a href="/Something2" shape-id="26">Something2</a>
</li>
<li class="last" shape-id="28">
<a href="/Something3" shape-id="28">Something3</a>
</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</article>
```

How do I influence the rendering of my menu's so that I can apply proper CSS to it? The only alternates that I can make either contain only:

```
<a href="@Model.Href">@Model.Text</a>
```

or:

```
@Display(Model.Menu)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a custom shape for the menu, inside Views/Menu-Main.cshtml, as explained on [this page](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes). From there on, you can pretty much do whatever you want to the shape. For example

```
@{
// Model is Model.Menu from the layout (Layout.Menu)
    var tag = Tag(Model, "ul");

    var items = (IList<dynamic>)Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>(Model.Items);

    if (items.Any()) {
        items[0].Classes.Add("first");
        items[items.Count - 1].Classes.Add("last");
    }    
}
<nav class='my-custom-class'>
    @tag.StartElement
        @DisplayChildren(Model)
    @tag.EndElement
</nav>
```

I haven't actually tried this so apologies if I'm not 100% correct, but this should get you in the right direction at least.

Also, the sample code above is just a slightly modified version of the original menu's code, best part about Orchard is that it's open source... You can view the original code [here](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b3601054d641#src/Orchard.Web/Core/Shapes/Views/Menu.cshtml)

Comment: I'll try this out. I'm working with the source version of Orchard btw,  however I want to prevent having to modify modules other than my own for maintainability reasons.

Comment: The answer I've given you doesn't require to modify the original source code, I just referenced it in case you needed to know where to start from.

Comment: You are right, you should never have to modify an existing module. Instead, copy the file into your theme and modify that.

Comment: Hmm, I'm looking into the views in the Navigation module and none of them seem to be responsible for the `<nav>` tag. What does the rendering of that?

Comment: To add to my last comment: it is the rendering of `@Display(Model.Menu)`

Comment: For the people coming here after me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170763/how-do-you-override-the-rendering-of-the-navigation-zone-in-orchard-cms made me understood the answer above.