# How to render an ad hoc shape before a widget

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have the following code in my Layout.cshtml to add the user controls to the header:

`WorkContext.Layout.Header.Add(New.User(), "10");`

In the header however the

`<article class="widget-HeaderMenu widget-header widget-menu-widget widget" shape-id="5">`

is rendered before

`<div class="user-display" shape-id="15">` (this is injected with that WorkContext stuff)

Both are float right, however the order needs to be reversed to make the user control appear on the right side of the menu.

How do I do that?

I'm curious if it does have something to do with the second parameter of `WorkContext.Layout.Header.Add(New.User(), "10");` that doesn't appear to do anything even if I set it to over 9000? I recognize the left parameter as the instantiation of a Clay object btw.

EDIT

After some experimentation it seems that the second parameter is the order of the injected shapes within the zone.

EDIT2

I got the effect that I wanted bij adding `<li>@Display(New.User())</li>` to the MenuWidget alternate.

The alternate will be:

```
@{
// Model is Model.Menu from the layout (Layout.Menu)
var tag = Tag(Model, "ul");

var items = (IList<dynamic>)Enumerable.Cast<dynamic>(Model.Items);

if (items.Any()) {
    items[0].Classes.Add("first");
    items[items.Count - 1].Classes.Add("last");
    }    
}
<nav id='topnav'>

    <ul>
       @DisplayChildren(Model.Menu)
        <li>@Display(New.User())</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

See also: [How to control the rendering of a menu in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019611/how-to-control-the-rendering-of-a-menu-in-orchard)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably for you to introduce a new zone.

Comment: The problem is that the user display (log-in) needs to be inserted in the same menu structure in the same zone.

Comment: You did not say that what you really wanted to do was something completely different, namely build a custom menu item. The solution you found is not good practice. Building a custom menu item type is the way to go here.